# Running a small IPTV station

Tags: linux, video, video-streaming

I'm looking to run an iptv station for my dorm.  I know I can serve multicast so that's not a problem. The station will serve out podcasts and other cc licensed content.  The target endpoint is xbmc- a media center. So far I know that I need to serve an rtp stream over udp that's streaming an mpeg-4 avc main or high profile with aac ( or ac3 ?) audio. I've had some luck using vlc with vlm to stream but it seems limited.  What are my other options?  Everything has to run on Linux- hopefully open source. How can I use playlists and not live streams?  What are my software options?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever looked at MythTV?  There's an addon for XBMC to talk to it.

Also, XBMC can play video etc direct from Samba shares, so no need for streaming software.